# Too Many False Negatives Using Google Cloud Vision Face Detection API

Tags: amazon-web-services, face-detection, google-cloud-vision, amazon-rekognition

I run the face detection API from [Google](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/detecting-faces) and [Amazon](https://aws.amazon.com/rekognition/) on 1,000 testing images. In the [results](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1u0OiRxZwsjX5Y4hW4j-tpB3zRcBixskj/view?usp=sharing), Google has a surprisingly high false negative rate.

Some examples:

Google: https://obj-manip.cs.princeton.edu/results/test/ILSVRC2012_test_00086325.google.jpg

Amazon: https://obj-manip.cs.princeton.edu/results/test/ILSVRC2012_test_00086325.amazon.jpg

Google: https://obj-manip.cs.princeton.edu/results/test/ILSVRC2012_test_00009871.google.jpg

Amazon: https://obj-manip.cs.princeton.edu/results/test/ILSVRC2012_test_00009871.amazon.jpg

While I understand face detectors are not perfect and they make errors that are hard to explain, the excessive false negative rate here makes me wonder if something has gong wrong. Maybe decreasing the threshold of the face detector will yield more detected face, but I don't see how to do that in [Google's documentation](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/apis).

This is the code I used

```py
    from google.cloud import vision
    from google.protobuf.json_format import MessageToJson
    import json
    # src: the filename of the input image
    # dst: the filename to store the detection results
    # return value: the number of detected faces
    # side effect: store the face detection results in dst
    def detect(self, src, dst):
        img = vision.types.Image(content=open(src, 'rb').read())
        response = json.loads(MessageToJson(self.client.face_detection(image=img)))
        json.dump(response, open(dst, 'wt'))
        if response == {}:
            return 0
        else:
            return len(response['faceAnnotations'])
```

Any idea of how to get Google detects more faces? Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried the Python code samples? https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/detecting-faces#vision_face_detection-python

Comment: @Simon I tried with a few examples and the results remain the same